# What to do with WordPress permalink on nginx?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I started a VPS yesterday and I installed WordPress and have done basic setup. But what is the deal with permalink? No one wish to use default ugly URL structure. I tried to understand http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress but funny thing is "I don't know where to insert those codes". They probably think all of their readers are well known with nginx, that's not funny.

So, I am pretty sure .htaccess is not working in nginx. Now what? Where to place which code to make Custom permalink work? P.S: You know, if I set a custom permalink then the output is 404 page like:

[image]

So please, I want a simple guide that tell like "edit demo.php file and place below code after X".

ADDITIONAL INFO: My webroot is /usr/share/nginx/html, and I have two WordPress there. First: /usr/share/nginx/html directory
and second: /usr/share/nginx/html/video directory. I want pretty url for both of them. I chmod wp-content to 775 for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx doesn't support .htaccess at all.

Is your nginx setup correctly so that php files are being processed by php-fpm?  Your error screen shot is unclear about that.

You have to edit your nginx config file and tell it to use the wordpress controller to direct requests through.

Your nginx.conf should have an http block, and within that a server block, and within that some location blocks.  You need to find the correct server block and insert the following location block

```
location / {
    # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Here is a complete example of a fully working wordpress nginx.conf I run:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 30;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name www.site.com;

        root /var/www;
        index index.php;

        location / {
            # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```